# How to remove the occurence of " characters from nsstring?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am familiar on how to remove the unwanted charaters such as `{,},<,>,` but i am not able to find on how to remove the occurence of "(inverted commas) in an **NSString**. Any suggestion on this would be of great help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverted commas are reserved chars in `objective c` and many other languages. So you have to escape them. In objective c (and many others) the special-reserved characters are escaped prepending a back slash `\` to the char.

So, if you have a string like this:

```
fsdfads"dsfdsa
```

which you can instantiate escaping the special char, inverted commas, like this:

```
NSString* s = @"fsdfads\"dsfdsa";
```

You can remove the inverted commas doing:

```
[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

Hope this helps!

EDITED:

You comment that you have a string like @"108" and you want to get the 108. If you want it as a NSString, you should do what I posted. If you want the 108 as a NSNumber, you should convert it from NSString to NSNumber. Use `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"108"];
[f release];   // If you are not using ARC
```

Comment: I am getting a string something like "108". I need to remove the occurence of " and then take just the number. Can u please help me on how to do this?

Comment: My String name is selectedlesson. I am getting the data from the server with " characters appended. I need to remove the " characters and then take the lesson number. I am not able to append the \ character to my string. Can u please help me on this?

Comment: You don't need to append the \ to the string, you have to prepend it when you use the 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString' method to escape the inverted commas in a literal string. Do something like this 'NSString* result = [selectedlesson stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];'

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa please tell me if this works, and mark the answer as correct if it solves the problem, so that others can find it easier

Comment: My string doesnt contain \ character. It just contains " character. Anyhow its working..Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Even when it's marked as accepted answer, I'll tell you: the \ is a special char used in objective c to escape other special chars, like the inverted commas. If you want to declare a string with inverted commas in it, if you do @"blabla"blabla" the compiler will not accept it because it reads the string just up to the first 'blabla'. So, to put those inverted commas in the middle, you prepend a \ to them, @"blabla\blabla". The same occurs when using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"", you can not write stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""", you need the \

Comment: Useful as the only reference to numberFromString example on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
NSString *strText = @"abcdef\"\"xyz";
[strText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about quotation marks, then use the following:

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

If you are talking about something else, still try using the escape character(setting `\` before that character)

Hope it helps